# ActiveRecord getId() method returns NULL

Tags: android, activerecord, android-sqlite

Hi i am using [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/) to store some data in a local DB and i get a very strange behaviour. I have created my table and when i try to retrieve the ID of an element using the getId() i get a null pointer exception... However all the other fields are there and not null.

Anyone has encountered this before?

Here is some code:

```
package ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel;

import java.io.Serializable;

import ro.gebs.captoom.database.CaptoomSQLiteHelper;

import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;

@Table(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.TABLE_MILEAGE)
public class Mileage extends Model implements Serializable, Comparable<Mileage>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID)
    private String folderId;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_START_DATE)
    private String startDate;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_END_DATE)
    private String endDate;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE)
    private String distance;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CURRENCY)
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_UNIT)
    private String unit;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRICE)
    private String price;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DETAILS)
    private String details;
    @Column(name = CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SYNC)
    private int isSynchronized;

    public Mileage(){
        super();
    }

    public Mileage(String folder_id, String start_date, String end_date, String distance, String currency, String unit, String price, String details, int synced){
        super();
        this.folderId = folder_id;
        this.startDate = start_date;
        this.endDate = end_date;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.price = price;
        this.details = details;
        this.setIsSynchronized(synced);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Mileage another) {
        return this.getId().compareTo(another.getId());
    }

    public String getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }

    public void setFolderId(String folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getIsSynchronized() {
        return isSynchronized;
    }

    public void setIsSynchronized(int isSynchronized) {
        this.isSynchronized = isSynchronized;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.details + "+++" + this.isSynchronized;
    }

}
```

and this is where i try to retrieve:

```
package ro.gebs.captoom.database;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import com.activeandroid.query.Select;

public class MileageDataSource {

    // sync variables
    public final int SYNC_ID = 0x7f020001;
    public final int NEW_NOT_SYNC_ID = 0x7f020011;

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private CaptoomSQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] columnsMileage = { CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_START_DATE,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_END_DATE,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DISTANCE,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CURRENCY,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_UNIT, CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRICE,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DETAILS,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SYNC,
            CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID };

    private boolean isOpen;

    public MileageDataSource(Context context) {
        setDbHelper(new CaptoomSQLiteHelper(context));
        isOpen = false;
    }

    public void open() {
        if (!isOpen) {
            isOpen = true;
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        if (isOpen) {
            isOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public Mileage createMileage(String folder_id, String start_date,
            String end_date, String distance, String currency, String unit,
            String price, String details) {
        Mileage newMileage = new Mileage(folder_id, start_date, end_date,
                distance, currency, unit, price, details, NEW_NOT_SYNC_ID);
        newMileage.save();
        return newMileage;
    }

    public Mileage updateMileage(long id, String folder_id, String start_date,
            String end_date, String distance, String currency, String unit,
            String price, String details) {
        Mileage r = this.getMileageByID(id);
        System.out.println("This mileage ID is the problem!!" + r.getId());
        r.setFolderId(folder_id);
        r.setStartDate(start_date);
        r.setEndDate(end_date);
        r.setDistance(distance);
        r.setCurrency(currency);
        r.setUnit(unit);
        r.setPrice(price);
        r.setDetails(details);
        r.setIsSynchronized(NEW_NOT_SYNC_ID);
        r.save();
        return r;
    }

    public void syncMileage(Mileage r) {
        r.setIsSynchronized(SYNC_ID);
        r.save();
    }

    public Mileage getMileageByID(long id) {
        Mileage r = new Mileage();
        ArrayList<Mileage> allMileages = this.selectAllMileages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allMileages.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("in getmileageby id:"
                    + allMileages.get(i).getId());
            if (allMileages.get(i).getId() == id) {

                r = allMileages.get(i);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public ArrayList<Mileage> selectAllMileages() {
        ArrayList<Mileage> allReceipts = new ArrayList<Mileage>();

        List<Mileage> selMileages = new Select().from(
                ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage.class).execute();
        allReceipts.addAll(selMileages);

        return allReceipts;
    }

    public ArrayList<Mileage> findMileagessByDate(String myDate, long folder_id) {
        ArrayList<Mileage> allMileages = new ArrayList<Mileage>();
        List<Mileage> selMileages = new Select()
                .from(ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage.class)
                .where(CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_END_DATE + "='" + myDate
                        + "' AND " + CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID
                        + " = " + folder_id).execute();
        allMileages.addAll(selMileages);
        return allMileages;
    }

    public ArrayList<Mileage> selectMileagesFromFolder(long folder_id) {
        ArrayList<Mileage> allMiles = new ArrayList<Mileage>();

        List<Mileage> selMiles = new Select()
                .from(ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage.class)
                .where(CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID + "=="
                        + String.valueOf(folder_id)).execute();
        allMiles.addAll(selMiles);

        return allMiles;
    }

    public int getUnsyncedMileagesCount(long folder_id) {
        List<Mileage> selReceipts = new Select()
                .from(ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage.class)
                .where(CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID + "=="
                        + String.valueOf(folder_id) + " AND "
                        + CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SYNC + "=="
                        + String.valueOf(NEW_NOT_SYNC_ID)).execute();
        return selReceipts.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Mileage> selectUnsyncedMileages() {
        ArrayList<Mileage> allMileages = new ArrayList<Mileage>();

        List<Mileage> selReceipts = new Select()
                .from(ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage.class)
                .where(CaptoomSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SYNC + "=="
                        + String.valueOf(NEW_NOT_SYNC_ID)).execute();
        allMileages.addAll(selReceipts);

        return allMileages;
    }

    public String[] getColumnsFolder() {
        return columnsMileage;
    }

    public void setColumnsFolder(String[] columnsFolder) {
        this.columnsMileage = columnsFolder;
    }

    public CaptoomSQLiteHelper getDbHelper() {
        return dbHelper;
    }

    public void setDbHelper(CaptoomSQLiteHelper dbHelper) {
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        this.database = database;
    }


}
```

The output to this `System.out.println("This mileage ID is the problem!!" + r.getId());` is null....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s maybe not a answer, but I need to show piece of code:

By reading through AndroidActive(I´ve never used it until now), It seems that You have to pass which columns You want to select on newSelect(). If You want to get all, it could be something like this:

```
    public ArrayList<Mileage> selectAllMileages() {
           ArrayList<Mileage> allReceipts = new ArrayList<Mileage>();

           List<Mileage> selMileages = new Select().all().from(  //put all() between
            ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage.class).execute();
           allReceipts.addAll(selMileages);

          return allReceipts;
     }
```

This could be the reason why Your getId() is returning null. But, like I said, it is just an asumption, I could not test it for now.